# WebService Asp.Net Json not serialize a List(Of Class)

Tags: json, vb.net, web-services, list, asmx

after a lot of time searching here and in the web, i'm posting my problem and my code for yours teach me how i do this works.

The problem is that the Json not serialize listUsuarios, when i use JavaScriptSerializer the return is "{}" and when i use JsonConvert.SerializeObject the return is "False".

Sorry for my bad english.

Here is the code...

USUARIOS.VB

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class Usuarios
    Private _Codigo As Long
    Private _Nome As String
    Private _Telefone As String

    Public Property Codigo As Integer
        Get
            Return _Codigo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Codigo = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Nome() As String
        Get
            Return _Nome
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Nome = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Telefone() As String
        Get
            Return _Telefone
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Telefone = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class ListUsuarios
    Private listUsuarios As List(Of Usuarios)

    Public Sub New()
        listUsuarios = New List(Of Usuarios)
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddItem(ByVal usuario As Usuarios)
        listUsuarios.Add(usuario)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub

    Public Function Item(ByVal Index As Integer) As Usuarios
        Return CType(listUsuarios.Item(Index), Usuarios)
    End Function

    Public Function Count() As Integer
        Return listUsuarios.Count
    End Function
End Class
```

ANDROID.VB

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Xml

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class Android
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Dim Dt As DataTable
    Dim Da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function Android(query As String) As String
        Dim listUsuario As ListUsuarios = carregaDadosAccess(query)
        Return retornaDadosJSON(listUsuario)
    End Function

    Private Function getConexaoDB() As OleDbConnection
        Try
            cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyLocalAccess").ConnectionString
            cn.Open()
            Return cn
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Sub closeConexaoDB(ByVal cn As OleDbConnection)
        Try
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cn.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function carregaDadosAccess(selectCommmand As String) As ListUsuarios
        Dim usuario As Usuarios = Nothing
        Dim listUsuario As New ListUsuarios
        Dim i As Long = 0

        Try
            cn = getConexaoDB()
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommmand, cn)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim arrImage() As Byte = Nothing
            Dim myMS As New IO.MemoryStream

            da.Fill(dt)

            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Do
                    usuario = New Usuarios
                    usuario.Codigo = dt.Rows(i).Item("key-codigo")
                    usuario.Nome = dt.Rows(i).Item("dad-descri")
                    usuario.Telefone = dt.Rows(i).Item("dad-telefo")

                    listUsuario.AddItem(usuario)

                    i = i + 1
                    If i = dt.Rows.Count Then Exit Do
                Loop
            Else
                listUsuario = Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            closeConexaoDB(cn)
        End Try

        Return listUsuario
    End Function

    Private Function retornaDadosJSON(listUsuario As ListUsuarios) As String
        'Json serializer do próprio .net
        'Dim JsonSerializer As New JavaScriptSerializer
        'Return JsonSerializer.Serialize(listUsuario)

        'Json serializer James Newton-King
        Dim JsonSerializer As String = ""
        Return JsonSerializer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listUsuario)
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Also, don't ever do `Try Catch ex As Exception Throw ex End Try`. That has no value and will mess up your stack trace to make it look like the exception _originated_ from the `Throw ex`.

Comment: Thank you for the warning, I'm still not used to working with WCF, but I need to know how to serialize this List! After that I will migrate to WCF!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is you are returning a value that compares an empty string with the serialized json string and since the json serialized string is not empty. This is where the result of "False" is coming from.

You can fix that problem by changing the method to:

```
Private Function retornaDadosJSON(listUsuario As ListUsuarios) As String
    Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listUsuario)
End Function
```

You can prevent this type of issue in the future by adding the following directives to the top of each file:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
```

or by setting the corresponding values in the project's Compile property page (you can also set these to default values for new projects in Visual Studio's Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VB Default).

`Option Strict On` would have prevented that code from compiling. It would also show you that there is a data type difference between _`Codigo` and `Codigo` (one is `Long` the other is `Integer`).

The second problem is that `ListUsuarios` isn't defined well for what you are trying to do with it. It would be much better to inherit from `List(Of Usuarios)` than your current design.

Changing to the following class will both reduce the code and ensure the data is serialized correctly:

```
Public Class ListUsuarios
    Inherits List(Of Usuarios)

    Public Sub AddItem(ByVal usuario As Usuarios)
        Me.Add(usuario)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank's, i've had already fixed the type of _Codigo and Codigo and a class ListUsuarios really did work! Great!